# Does changing the order of the indices of the Kronecker delta within a summation matter?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, index-notation, kronecker-delta

In my notes I have that

> $$\sum_m a_m \delta_{nm}=a_1\delta_{n1}+a_2\delta_{n2}+a_3\delta_{n3}+\cdots=a_n\tag{A}$$

Is this really correct?

I thought that for the Kronecker delta the first index *must* match the summation index. For this reason, I thought that the expression $(\mathrm{A})$ should written as

$$\sum_\color{blue}{m} a_m \delta_{\color{blue}{m}n}=a_1\delta_{1n}+a_2\delta_{2n}+a_3\delta_{3n}+\cdots=a_n\tag{B}$$

Just to make my argument clear, I have made the color of the indices match.

After looking at [this page on the Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) I know that it is okay to write 
$$\sum_ja_j\delta_{ij}=a_i\tag{1}$$ 
or
$$\sum_ia_i\delta_{ij}=a_j\tag{2}$$

Expression $(1)$ matches $(\mathrm{A})$ and expression $(2)$ matches $(\mathrm{B})$

---

So does this mean that switching the order of the indices of the Kronecker delta (within a summation) has no effect on the result (the RHS), or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kronecker symbol $\delta_{ij}$ is used to say $\delta_{ii}=1$ and $\delta_{ij}=0$ if $i \neq j$.

**This is independent of any summation.** Kronecker symbol can be used in general. That being said, the evaluation of formula $(A)$ is perfectly correct as the only term that is not vanishing is when index $m$ is equal to $n$.

Comment: So is it okay to switch the order of the indices or not (the question I'm asking)?

Comment: I updated the answer. In the specific case of sum $(A)$, you can indeed switch the indices.

Answer (score 1):

By its definition, $\delta_{i,j}=\delta_{j,i},$ [one can drop the commas as you have]  one can switch the indices *anywhere*, in a sum or otherwise.

Comment: Please note that the comma at this point may also have a different meaning: Partial derivation with respect to a spatial coordinate. This is used for example in continuum mechanics.

Comment: @Philipp Thanks, didn't know about that. Then if it's partial derivative, could it sometimes  fail to be commutative?

Comment: Yes, it may be. It is not part of the fundamental tensor calculus but used often as a shorthand to allow for more compact notation. In the case of the comma notation the index can even appear more than two times: $a_{ii,ii}$ is $\frac{\partial a_{11}}{\partial^2 x_1} + \frac{\partial a_{22}}{\partial^2 x_2} + \frac{\partial a_{33}}{\partial^2 x_3} $